# Data From Excel Using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge, rows

I have an old excel spreadsheet with a lot of data in a relational database type format, with one main primary key that I need to go through.

I want to compare some rows but there are many entries (thousands of rows, dozens of columns) and Excel doesn't really have built-in features to do this. After looking around I found out the best way to extract the data is using a script with Python, but I have no programming skills in python or any language for the matter. I need to look for duplicates in the key column and then check if there are duplicates rows in that same column and if so merge them in a new row and then a new excel file/sheet separating the merged rows from the non-merged rows.

I don't know if this sounds too complicated or not and I am new here so I did do some research scouring the internet to see if I can find any scripts to do it but no luck really... Here are the closest posts I found that may have something to do with what I want but what I found usually is about people wanting to merge 2 different excel files together:

http://pbpython.com/excel-file-combine.html

[Looking to merge two Excel files by ID into one Excel file using Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661836/looking-to-merge-two-excel-files-by-id-into-one-excel-file-using-python-2-7)

(I have more links but could only post two.)

Basically i'm looking for duplicate rows and want to merge them together into a new file or spreadsheet in excel, separating them from the non dupes and putting it all back together.

Comment: The question is too general for this forum. You should post some code that you have tried, and report the issues you encountered. See [MCVE] for help.

Comment: I only copied what I saw from the links....and they merge excel files, entirely so......not what I want to do as I said. And my question seems more specific then anything else1